# Get whole week date starting from sunday to saturday from given date

Tags: php

Hello guys i am working in php and my requirement is to get complete week dates from given date as i need to calculate weekly working hour. And week must be started from sunday to saturday not monday to sunday. I have code which works properly for other days of week except sunday. it means if give any dates from monday to saturday it works properly but if i give sunday's date it give last week's dates. please check my code and advise me for better solution.

```
$days = array();                
$ddate = "2018-01-07";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
$y =    date("Y", strtotime($ddate));
echo "Weeknummer: $week"."<br>";
echo "Year: $y"."<br>";             
for($day=0; $day<=6; $day++)
{
    $days[$day] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($y."W".$week.$day))."<br>";
}               
print_r($days);
```

Comment: Ok so you require date from monday to sunday from 1st jan to 7th jan ? or require date from 31st dec to 6th jan as sunday to saturday ?

Comment: Please have a look at the DatePeriod class. [link](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Comment: @jilesh, from 31st dec to 6th jan as sunday to saturday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [source](https://www.redips.net/php/week-list-current-date/),

Here is the snippet you are looking for,

```
// set current date
$date = '01/03/2018';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset*86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday 
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400){
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7dfd315ed81ab884d62ed7d78bf1a1f41e406e63).

If you need normal standard format code,

Here is your snippet,

```
// set current date
$date = '2018-01-03';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow    = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400) {
    print date("Y-m-d l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c264316eda3a41ee6757db9d10f8cb4ba94e78d).

**EDIT**

As per your requirement, now week will start from sunday to saturday

```
<?php
// set current date
$date = '2018-01-03';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Sunday
$dow    = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Sunday
$ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
// loop from Sunday till Saturday
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400) {
    print date("Y-m-d l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: did not work, it gives monday to sunday but i want sunday to saturday

Comment: @vasdevchandrakar Please check my edit portion for your requirement

Comment: Happy to help @vasdevchandrakar

Answer (score 2):

Using the `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod` classes you could do it like this perhaps

```
function getperiod( $start ){
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime( $start ),
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        new DateTime( date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $start . '+ 7days' ) ) )
    );
}

$start='2018-01-07';

$period=getperiod( $start );
foreach( $period as $date ){
    echo $date->format('l -> Y-m-d') . '<br />';
}
```

Which returns

```
Sunday -> 2018-01-07
Monday -> 2018-01-08
Tuesday -> 2018-01-09
Wednesday -> 2018-01-10
Thursday -> 2018-01-11
Friday -> 2018-01-12
Saturday -> 2018-01-13
```

Or, by modifying the parameters of the `getperiod` function you can make that function far more flexible.

```
function getperiod( $start, $interval='P1D', $days=7 ){
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime( $start ),
        new DateInterval( $interval ),
        new DateTime( date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $start . '+ '.$days.' days' ) ) )
    );
}

$start='2018-01-07';
$days=array();

$period=getperiod( $start );
foreach( $period as $date ){
    $days[]=$date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($days,true),'</pre>';
```

For instance: To find every Sunday for the next year

```
$period=getperiod( $start,'P7D', 365 );
foreach( $period as $date ){
    $days[]=$date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($days,true),'</pre>';
```

---

To ensure that the calculations begin on a `Sunday` which has a numeric value of `7`

```
function getperiod( $start, $interval='P1D', $days=7 ){
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime( $start ),
        new DateInterval( $interval ),
        new DateTime( date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $start . '+ '.$days.' days' ) ) )
    );
}

/* A date from which to begin calculations */
$start='2018-01-01';

/* Array to store output */
$days=array();

/* integer to represent which day of the week to operate upon */
$startday = 7;

/* Output format for resultant dates */
$output='Y-m-d';

/* Calculate initial startdate given above variables */
$start=date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( $start . ' + ' . ( $startday - date( 'N', strtotime( $start ) ) ) . ' days' ) );

/* Get the period range */
$period=getperiod( $start );
foreach( $period as $date ){
    /* store output in desired format */
    $days[]=$date->format( $output );
}

/* do something with data */
echo '<pre>',print_r($days,true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: it is not working as expected, it gives 7 days start from given date if i give 6 then it starts from 6, but i want sunday to saturday for given date means if i give 6 it should start from 31 to 6, similarly for 7 - 7 to 13, for 8 - 7 to 13... and so on

Comment: means it should start from sunday to saturday of any given date

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using the Date classes of php is the most common way. You don 't need to write your own functions, which exactly do the same as the Date classes of php.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$days = array();                
$ddate = "2018-01-07";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("N")==7?$date->modify("+1 week")->format("W"):$date->format("W");
$y =    date("Y", strtotime($ddate));
echo "Weeknummer: $week"."<br>";
echo "Year: $y"."<br>";             
for($day=0; $day<=6; $day++)
{
    $days[$day] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($y."W".$week.$day))."<br>";
}               
print_r($days);
```

Comment: sorry didn't realize that W returns "01" instead of 1... my bad, I updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$days = array();                
$ddate = "2018-01-07";
$y =    date("Y", strtotime($ddate));
if(date("l", strtotime($ddate))=='Sunday'){
    $ddate = date("Y-m-d ", strtotime($ddate. "+1 day"));
}
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
echo "<br/>";
echo "Weeknummer: $week"."<br>";
echo "Year: $y"."<br>";             
for($day=0; $day<=6; $day++)
{
    $days[$day] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($y."W".$week.$day))."<br>";

}               
print_r($days);





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dto = new DateTime();

$year = date_create($this->week_date)->format('o');

$week_no = date('W', strtotime($this->week_date));

$dto->setISODate($year, $week_no);

$dto->modify('-1 days');

$ret['sunday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');

$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['monday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['tuesday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['wednesday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['thursday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['friday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['saturday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['next_sunday'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
```